# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I was typing this code to display the table's info in txt boxes but I found a problem here:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

Id
                    Name
                    Email
                    Country
                    City
                
                
                    1
                    Aymen Zitouni
                    Email   
                    Country 
                    City    
                
                   
    
    
        var tbl = document.getElementsByClassName("TableInfo");
        document.write(tbl.rows.length);
        for (var x = 1 ; x

```
<form class="InfoForm" method="POST">
    <div>
        <label>ID</label> <input type="text" id="txtNumber">
        <br><br>
        <label>Name</label> <input type="text"  id="txtName">
        <br><br>
        <label>Email</label> <input type="email"  id="txtEmail">
        <br><br>
        <label>Country</label>  <select id="txtCountry"><option>Tunisia</option>
                                        <option>Germany</option>
                                        <option>Italy</option>
                                        <option>America</option>
                                </select>
        <br><br>
        <label>City</label> <input type="text"  id="txtCity">
        <br><br>
        <button>Show</button>
        <button>Insert</button>
        <button>Delete</button>
        <button>Update</button>
    </div>                        
</form>
```

Comment: try to use `tbl.length` instead of `tbl.rows.length`

Comment: no I have to type tbl.rows.length because the loop will read each row and get infos to show them in txtBoxes

Comment: Also define `ids` for each column element.

Comment: @Aymen haye you tried it ? just try it first

Comment: @Aymen put an id to the table for better approach

Comment: I put id but still the same

Comment: when i type tbl. and i'm waiting the vs code to suggest me length it doesn't give me length suggest so I wrote with myself

Comment: @Mijanur Rahaman i tried it bro there's no problem shown but it doesn't work

Comment: @Aymen then share your complete codes, here your codes are incomplete

Comment: @Mijanur Rahaman i put the completed code

Comment: @Aymen its not showing all of your codes

Comment: @Aymen your question is closed, you can see the pen here I have solved it https://codepen.io/imijanur/pen/xxRvQPJ?editors=1111

Comment: @Mijanur Rahaman thanks a lot